# ActionMode OnCreateActionMode not called

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app with a contextual action bar but the onCreateActionMode is not being called, nor is the listview item being set selected, nor is the itemcheckstatechanged listener working.

Below is how I am creating the action mode:

```
AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener mOnItemLongClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {

            if (mActionMode != null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            lstRooms.setOnItemClickListener(null);
            mActionMode = getActivity().startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
            view.setSelected(true);

            return true;
        }
    };
```

Below is how I set the OnLongItemClickListener

```
lstRooms.setOnItemLongClickListener(mOnItemLongClickListener);
```

Below is my ActionMode Callback.

```
private ActionMode.Callback mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            lstRooms.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            lstRooms.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
                {
                    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.room_context_menu, menu);
                    mode.setTitle("HELLO WORLD");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
                {

                }
            });
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item)
        {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode)
        {
            mActionModeCallback = null;
        }


    };
```

None of the method such as the onCreateActionMode is called so my title bar isn't set, although the action bar does turn black, for some reason, I know the the text should be white as if I do `actionMode.setTitle("Hello")` after I create the object it works, it's just the call back functions aren't working.

As mentioned the other problem is that list view item doesn't show that its selected when I do `view.setSelected(true)` I've also tried `lstRoom.setItemChecked(position, true)`.

Comment: Where did you set the listener to the view? I only see its declaration...

Comment: What listener are you referring too, I think I have included everything from the instructions from what I can tell, I've start the action mode from the list view on long click

Comment: Something like `adapterView.setOnItemLongClickListener(mOnItemLongClickListener)`.  Does your Toast `Long Click` appear?

Comment: I've added it to my question, didn't think it was related as the on click is working (I do get long click and the action bar updates from Red to Black, but none of the menu, or text is updated, nor are items shown as selected)

Comment: For the second problem, try this too : `parent.requestFocusFromTouch(); parent.setSelection(position);`, instead of `view.setSelected(true);` ,  see if it works...

Comment: That second option has worked, interestingly, if I do the long click, the first time it selects the view, if I then press back on the action bar to clear the CAB, do the long click again, this time the set selection doesn't work, but the action bar toolbar title is set and the menu is inflated. I'm a little confused as to why this might happen

Comment: I don't understand either, but if I were you, I would set breakpoints in the `callBack`  methods and in listener code and see when they are called and how they behave... maybe you've done this already, don't know, but it seems a good aproach to me!

Comment: Yea I have done, doesn't really tell me anything I don't know, the first time the prepareActionMenu is not called

Comment: Have you read [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159527) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to figured out what the problem was.

I had a misunderstanding of how the multi choice mode listener worked. What I was doing was register OnItemLongClickListener then within the Listener, set it to multi choice, then in there create the ActionMode.Callback and then create the MultiChoice listener. I didn't realise the MulitiChoiceListener can actually create the ActionMode.Callback itself so they were conflicting with each other.

Instead I get rid of all of that, and just create a MultiChoiceModeListener which creates the contextual action bar itself.